# Azure app: how to log POSTed JSON to my app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I went to my App services > my app > Monitoring > Diagnostic logs

And there I enabled both: `Application Logging (Blob)` and `Web server logging (Storage)`

The above settings started logging a .log file in which every row is an HTTP request to my app, with these headers:

```
#Fields: date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
```

I'm interested in logging the POSTed JSON for the requests that the server is responding HTTP 500. **How can I achieve this from the Azure portal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve this from the Azure portal?

Azure Web App doesn't provide this feature default. I suggest you add a event handler for application level exception. In this handler, you could log the request body or the information of exception. Code below is for your reference.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string req_JSON;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        req_JSON = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    //you could log the json to anywhere you want 

    Exception excpt = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    //you also could log the exception which encounted at server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are using to write your app, but if you are using .net you would need to use the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` namespace.

in this case since you are getting a 5XX http error, I asume there is some sort of exception being thrown that is missing a try/catch.

Once you find that, then you add something like:

System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("If you're seeing this, something bad happened " + postedJSON);

This will result in the json being added to the application log.

You can get more info about App Service logging here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: But to find out what is the Exception I need to know what is causing it. I want to know what is being sent from the user when the server is responding 5xx